# WinRT Background Task

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I have a winRT app that plays music, I want to enable background audio. My MediaElement is in [Solution]\Player\PlayerView.xaml

What should startup page be in the Background Taks properties?

I've tried: PlayerView.xaml, Player\PlayerView.xaml with no luck, maybe I am missing some other properties?

Thank you,

Comment: @Ramhound I followed exactly this tutorial, they set MainPage.xaml in the startup path, but as I said in the question I have PlayerView inside a folder Player and I don't really want to have all my views in the root folder is pretty messy.

Answer (score 1):

Start Page is for if you are using a JS project. Entry point is for XAML. You actually shouldn't need to declare anything for your background task besides the audio ability because the dispatcher handles all of the background work using

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => mediaplayer.DoSomething());
```

You would only be entering the Start Page/Entry Point if you created a WinMD(also known as Windows Runtime Library, not portable) Library that would run some sort of background task. This would also be C# code, not XAML. The background worker does not have a UI component